# Same values in MySQL not being grouped

Tags: mysql

I have two columns in two separate tables (both varchar(45)) and they both have values such as 0123456.

I have a union query which basically stacks the rows from both tables.

```
select 
'ISSUED' AS action,
card_match_key AS card_match_key,
count(0) AS CNT
from
dim_consumer_cards
group by 1 , 2 

union 

select 
'REDEEMED' AS action,
card_match_key AS card_match_key,
count(0) AS CNT
from
fct_card_redemptions
group by 1 , 2
```

Then a second query which forms a crosstab on the stacked data.

```
Select
card_match_key as cardkey,
sum(case when action = 'ISSUED' then CNT else 0 end) as ISSUED,
sum(case when action = 'REDEEMED' then CNT else 0 end) as REDEEMED
from vw_rpt_matchkey1
group by 
card_match_key
```

My issue/question is that my values are not being grouped on like values (e.g. 0123456).
Each value should only appear on a single row, but I'm getting two rows.

Comment: If they aren't being grouped, then they *aren't* the same value. Or the results are being read wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your first query to use a common sub-expression as follows:

```
with (
     select 
     'ISSUED' AS action,
     card_match_key AS card_match_key,
     from
     dim_consumer_cards
     UNION ALL
     select 
     'REDEEMED' AS action,
     card_match_key AS card_match_key,
     from
     fct_card_redemptions) AS combined
select action, card_match_key, count(1) as CNT
from combined
group by 1,2;
```

You need to do the union operation before you do the group-by.

Comment: "..Then a second query which forms a crosstab on the stacked data." This operation should flatten along the group's specified in said final query.